# How to insert a widget inside forum inself in vbulletin?

Tags: forum, vbulletin

You know, the publishing suite offers other content than forum. for example blogs and also some custom content

i know how to add articles/widgets to the page itself, but how do i add such a thing into a forum secion?

for example, on the left column i would have forums and on the right column i would have some news reader widget

could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is enough for you to enable the "forum sidebar" in the admincp.

admincp->Settings->Options->Forum Sidebar and Block Options->Enable Forum Sidebar=YES.

Now you can add custom blocks with HTML and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For vBulletin 3.x, the solution is to edit the appropriate templates (FORUMDISPLAY, SHOWTHREAD, etc). I can't be much more specific than that, I'm afraid, since the exact details will vary depending on what kind of modifications you've already made to your templates and the exact details of the widgets you wish to insert.